# Curl POST into pycurl code

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm trying to convert following curl request into pycurl:

```
curl -v \
--user username:passwd \
-H X-Requested-By:MyClient \
-H Accept:application/json \
-X POST \
http://localhost:7001/some_context
```

And it works. The following doesn't work:

```
import pycurl, json

url = "http://localhost:7001/some_context"
c = pycurl.Curl()
data = json.dumps(None)
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'X-Requested-By:MyClient'])
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "username:passwd")
c.perform()
```

But executing this I have an error 415: Unsupported media type. Do you have any idea? I would rather stay with pycurl- I know about requests library...

Comment: I note that inthe first sample, you pass no data. In the second, you pass an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string.

Comment: Here is helpful technique: replace the URL in both examples with `http://httpbin.org/post` and examien the verbose output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script mimicks your `curl` command line except for the URL. I have replaced your URL so that we can both test the same server.

```
import pycurl, json

url = "http://localhost:7001/some_url"
url= 'http://httpbin.org/post'
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json',
                             'X-Requested-By:MyClient',
                             'Content-Type:',
                             'Content-Length:'])
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "username:passwd")
c.perform()
```

Comment: I tried editing this twice and it got rejected both times. So let's try a comment. Please remove the second assignment to `url` from your example code. It is not part of the original post and it makes the first assignment (which *is* part of the original code) pointless. It is probably just something that was missed during a copy/paste. Hopefully @avariant and @Suraj Kumar don't reject it...

Comment: No, @Z4-tier , it was not accidentally missed. It is included purposefully in order to convert the OP non-working sample into an actual working sample. Perhaps my intention was unclear and I should have added a comment.

Comment: It's not that it is unclear. Rather, as it is currently written, the statement 'This script mimicks your curl command line:' is not true. Sorry to split hairs, but the topic is programming, and program correctness is important.

Comment: Thanks, @Z4-tier. I didn't pick up on your concern from your proposed edit. Hopefully my recent change addresses your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your post data is wrong, according to the http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-data it is expecting a dict, not a string. (`json.dumps(None) == 'null'`)

The error you get from your webserver is most likely related to that.

```
import pycurl, json

url = "http://localhost:7001/some_url"
c = pycurl.Curl()
data = {'whatever_field': None}
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'X-Requested-By:MyClient'])
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "username:passwd")
c.perform()
```